# Tell an image to cover the whole browser window

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i am working on a bootstrap-based website and i have placed a big image on top of it.

```
<div class="container-fluid introimage">
    <img src="img/wald.gif">
</div>
```

Now i want the container to be only as high as the browser-window is and i like to have the image to be aligned on bottom of the container, to get sure, that the bottom of the image is always visible.

I've tried something, but it did not work at all:

```
.introimage {height: 100%;}
.introimage img {vertical-align: bottom;}
```

Could you please help me? Thanks in advance!

This is the website: http://baustelle.injuvik.de

Comment: does the `<div>` wrapping your image takes 100% of height and width ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the image in the background of the container.

Simply apply these styles to your website, and it should work

```css
body, html {
height:100%;
}

.introimage {
 height: 100%;
 background-image: url(img/wald.gif);
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: bottom;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use `min-height:100%` with `height:100%` on body

```
.introimage {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the unit `vh` . It represent viewport height, and go from 0 to 100.

```
.introimage{
    height:100vh;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add following rules in your style sheet, What I have done is set the container to position fixed; so that it works w.r.t screen and made its height, width 100% so that it covers complete screen, then I aligned the element from top left corner and in the last set the image to cover complete parent div thus indirectly covering compelte browser window.

```
.introimage {
    height: 100%; 
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%
}
.introimage img {
    height:100%;
    width:100%
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the newer `vh` measurement for your stage, which will make any element the height of the veiwport with a value of 100.

```
.introimage {
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color:transparent;
}
```

I would then use that image as a background image as opposed to just an image tag.  I'd probably add it to the after pseudo-element of `.introimage`.

```
.introimage:after {
    content:'';
    display:block;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center bottom fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/